# Using system() after fopen() and before the corresponding fclose() (file descriptor leak)

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

I'm trying to understand the fundamentalities of the file descriptor leaking problem. (**If you don't know what it is, just post some code that fits the example.**)

So far, I've categorized applications into several types. What I've come up with is that, in POSIX generally, *ones that invokes other programs are cautious enough to set CLOEXEC flags on files they don't need child processes to handle*.

But there's obviously some programs that uses only the standard C library, and opens files and invokes system commands.

So is there an example  *(of a valid program)*  that **fopen()s a file, and system() a command, before close()ing it**?

I'm looking for examples in C, Objective-C, or PHP. Other languages are also accepted as long as it doesn't have garbage collection.

## 2016-08-26

I guess the pure C language programs won't use system(). Because:

1. They've no idea what system commands are available.
2. Ones know what system commands are available, usually know how to use those functionalities through library routines.
3. It's unlikely that system() would be the equivalent of the GNU syscall() functions on any platform.

For those who're not quite clear about what I'm asking for, I'm asking for an example of valid  *working*  program that (possibly due to bad programming practice), uses system() commands while FILE*s are fopen()'ed. And it's for helping me (and others) understand the fundamentalities of the file descriptor leaking problem.

### Also

I've noticed some Apple Pro Apps such as Final Cut Pro X have child processes handling media file decoding and frame rendering. At first I thought these would be valid examples of apps that opens file and creates child process.

But, after I looked up XPC on my Mac, I found out these services are started by launchd, and listed as if they were child processes through some special attributes. Which means their FD tables are clean.

Comment: I think you may need to reword this question. I was going to write this off as a Markov chain until I got near the end, and I'm still not sure exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @user4581301, I'm looking for a program using only standard C library, and calls system() between an fopen() and an fclose().

Comment: That's part of my problem with the question. Writing this should be trivial.

Comment: Why are you looking at garbage collection? Garbage collection frees memory, not file handles. Secondly, what is your concern? C and C++ don't know about file descriptors, that's a POSIX thing. C has `FILE*` and C++ has `std::fstream`, neither of which are inherited anyway.

Comment: 1) I've no concern with garbage collection. I presume ones with garbage collection automatically closes excessive FDs prior to creating child processes. 2) I'm wondering if there's valid C programs that'd leak file descriptors through the system() function. 3) I know that, I checked FreeBSD source code, it has an implementation-specific flag that sets the CLOEXEC flag, but most portable programs don't use it, so FDs may leak if fcntl is not used.

Comment: I don't understand why you are looking for an example when you can so easily write one yourself. As it stands, this is merely a request for an offsite resource and therefore off-topic.

Comment: @EJP Actually it turns out, it's quite difficult, there's no example on the other parts of the web, and I can't think of a proper and actually **useful** program that does this. I've already came up with conclusions, and I want to verify it. I thought here is full of codes, maybe someone would have one, and if no one has one, then my point will be proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard has no notion of file descriptors, hence no notion of file descriptor leakage.

How exactly a C implementation deals with the issue — by forcing `CLOEXEC` on any file descriptors opened by `fopen`, or by manually closing files before invoking `exec`, or by ignoring it altogether — is entirely up to the implementation.

`gcc` seems to ignore the issue, so if your program opens too many files and calls `system`, the program invoked by `system` may not be able to open any additional files. A simple demonstration is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void toomanyfiles()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (f)
    {
        toomanyfiles();
        fclose (f);
    }
    else
        system ("cat example.txt");
}

int main ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        system ("cat example.txt");
        toomanyfiles();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good example of exploiting the system, rather than a valid working program. I guess such program won't exist anywhere other than student's homeworks. If there's no better answer, then I'll accept yours. Thank you.

Comment: Also, would you mind discussing from the perspective of programming practice, the issue as said in the title of my question?

Comment: A sloppy programmer can exhaust finite OS resources. If that's an issue, then the soluftion is not to be sloppy. I don't see anything uniquely applicable to fopen and system here.

Answer (score 0):

I can easily think of several tens of examples that does that, but non of those are actually useful programs - all of them are simply meant to exploit the system capability rather than providing functions.

So the conclusion would be that: In any **proper and valid** programming paradigm, such example would not exist.